# How to cross compile

Tags: go, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm just building simple application for `linux ARM64` bit architecture from `linux amd64` bit architecture but at time of building GOlang builder  giving error to binding some libraries as below

`go build github.com/DataDog/zstd: build constraints exclude all Go files in`

I just wanted to know that for building different cross compile architecture is any libraries of that particular architecture is needed?
ex. if I'm building for `ARM64` libraries then `ARM64` supported libraries installed on my system?

Thanks

Comment: Running `go build` does not crosscompile. You should do a `GOARCH=amd64 go build ...` to cross compile. TO crosscompile plain Go code all you need is part of your Go installation. If a package needs special C libraries: Consult that package's documentation.

Comment: As Volker said, the official Go SDK is capable to cross-compile to the supported OS and architecture combinations without the need of additional files and tools. Whether a 3rd-party package has everything it needs is another question.

Comment: command to compile cross environment that `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build` still it giving error as I've mention. I'm really not getting what error actually is :(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting environmental variable as follows. You may need to go get your external dependencies first after that, before you'll go build.
    GOARCH = "arm64"

Comment: Already done it...Still got issue so that's why I posted question to get additional info about cross compilation